# flutter autocomplete suggestion like bing search

Tags: android, flutter, autocomplete, autofill, autosuggest

How to implement these types of auto suggestion feature in flutter app.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cc60Y.png)

I am expecting my input field look look like the image I provided with.
I am wondering how can I achieve this kind od feature in my flutter app. As you noticed most of the chat bots like bing chat and bing search use this feature you can notice teams app also suggest autosuggestion like this.

Comment: you will need a API with full textsearch capable where u can post partial words and it will return list of possible words/sentences. and then use https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_typeahead
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74902861/flutter-textformfield-suggestion-or-auto-complete